# Como verificar se um usuário ja enviou um arquivo em Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, formulário, plugin-wordpress, ux, usercontrol

Estou utilizando o plugin `WPForms`, versão PRO e adicionei um `button` de upload file neste formulário.

No entanto, preciso fazer a seguinte checagem:

- Um usuário envia um arquivo através do meu formulário. Quando esse mesmo usuário voltar, e fizer outro upload, como eu faço para checar se ele já fez algum envio previamente? E como faço para alterar o conteúdo da página, diante dessa condição?

Ps: já fiz uma função que verifica se o usuário está logado ou não, e o formulário só aparece para usuários logados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, encontrei a resposta. Basicamente, para você fazer o tracking, é so usufruir do banco de dados. Criei um script para verificar se o usuario está logado (tudo isso no functions.php):

```
function check_user ($params, $content = null){
//verifica se o usuario esta logado
if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
//coloque o que vc quer fazer...``
}
```

e dentro desse bloco de código, criei uma conexão com o banco de dados, e também peguei o ID do usuário, com o código (o de conexão não está aqui, mas é bem simples de fazer):

```
$id = get_current_user_id();
```

depois criei uma query string, pra dar um SELECT na tabela que me fazia sentido checar e consegui trazer os resultados com o seguinte comando (após executar a query string com a conexão em uma variável de nome result) :

```
$row = $mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

após isso, fiz a checagem (eu estava olhando para a coluna 'action' do meu banco de dados):

```
if($row['action'] == "upload"){
$data = utf8_encode("Você já fez um upload");
echo($data);
}
else{
$data = utf8_encode("Você ainda não fez nenhum upload");
echo($data);
}`
```

Espero ter ajudado :)